# $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\left(1-\cos^2\left(2x\right)\right)}{4-4\sin^2\left(x\right)}\cdot \left(x^{-2x}+x^{1-2x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)$

Tags: limits

$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\left(1-\cos^2\left(2x\right)\right)}{4-4\sin^2\left(x\right)}\cdot \left(x^{-2x}+x^{1-2x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)$

I have tried to convert the equation to $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\left(\sin^2{2x}\right)}{4\cos^2\left(x\right)}\cdot \left(x^{-2x}+x^{1-2x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)$

However I'm stuck and not sure what the next step is. Does it have someting to do with $\lim_{x\to c}{f(x)}=0, \lim_{x\to c}{g(x)}=0, \lim_{x\to c}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=L, => \lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L$ ?
And if so, how to I make the bottom part of the left equation approach 0 as x approaches 0, and not 4?

Comment: Hint: in terms of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) function, whose $x\to0$ limit is famous, you want $\lim_{x\to0}(1+x)^{1/x}\operatorname{sinc}^2x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the double angle formula to get
\begin{align*}y&=\dfrac{4\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)}{4\cos^2(x)}(x^{-2x}+x^{-2x+1})^{\frac{1}{x}}\\ &=\sin^2(x)(x^{-2x}+x^{-2x+1})^{\frac{1}{x}}]\\&=\sin^2(x)(x^{-2x}(1+x))^{\frac{1}{x}}\\
&=\dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\end{align*}

> By taking logarithm on both sides, \begin{align*}\lim_{x\to 0}\ln(y)=\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\ln\left(\dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\right)+\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\right]=1\end{align*} Note that these two parts can be evaluated separately. The first term is a well-known limit, and the second term can be evaluated using L'Hopital's Rule. Therefore, $$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{1-\cos^2\left(2x\right)}{4-4\sin^2\left(x\right)}\cdot \left(x^{-2x}+x^{1-2x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}e^{\ln(y)}=e$$

Comment: Thank you! Just one question (sorry if it's a stupid one) - where does the plus come from in the RHS of the first equation in the spoiler, why are the two logs not multiplied?

Comment: @JohnDoe It comes from the logarithm because $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$. In our case, $a=\sin^2(x)/x^2$ and $b=(1+x)^{1/x}$.

Comment: Of course, thanks!